# SQL-Invalid column name

Tags: sql

I have 3 temp tables , using 2 temp tables i will join and create a new temp table using "into" command. In the two parent tables i have a column named abc but when i use the same in the join condition i get an error mentioning invalid column name.

Invalid column name 'abc'.

can anyone help with the issue

Comment: Edit your question and (1) tag the question with the database you are using.  (2) Show the code that you have.

Comment: show the basic structure and code.

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Can't answer this question without seeing your table(s) and your sql. I'm going to believe your database that `'abc' is Invalid Column Name`

Comment: You can't have the same column name `abc` twice in your 3rd temp table. Name them `abc1` and `abc2` or whatever.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you need to be more specific about which column you mean, since both tables have a column with the same name.  Aliases may make this more convenient.

```
INSERT #mytemptableC (x, y, z)
select a.q, a.p, b.r
from #mytemptableA a inner join #mytemptableB b on a.q=b.q
```

Also, if your `abc` column has a complex name with symbols or spaces, such as `col #1`, you may need to enclose it in square braces `[col #1]`.

Without seeing the existing code, though, it is difficult to guess.  Please reply with your existing SQL statement and I'm sure the answer will be provided very quickly.